# Middleware return $next($request) with parameter

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I have a question, I created a middleware multi auth to restrict access for each user roles (roles 1, 2,3 ,4 ,5 ,6), but the problem is that all user roles can't access the page that I have set and redirect to dashboard.

Only manageusers page can be accessed by roles:1, when I try to add access to manageusers page on roles:3 then those who have access to manageusers page are roles:1 and roles:3. I try to login with roles:1 it doesn't even work to access manageusers page and then redirect to dashboard, otherwise when I try to login with roles:3 can access manageusers page.

any ideas on how to properly implement this?

Middleware CekUserLogin

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $rules)
    {
        if(!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->roles == $rules) {
            return $next($request);
        }
            
            return redirect('login')->with('error', "You don't have permission to access this page.");
    }
```

Kernel

```
'cekUserLogin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CekUserLogin::class
```

Route

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cekUserLogin:1'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users');
    Route::get('salesorder', [SoController::class, 'index'])->name('salesorder');
    Route::get('purchaseorder', [PoController::class, 'index'])->name('purchaseorder');
});
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cekUserLogin:2'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('salesorder', [SoController::class, 'index'])->name('salesorder');
    Route::get('purchaseorder', [PoController::class, 'index'])->name('purchaseorder');
});
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cekUserLogin:3'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('salesorder', [SoController::class, 'index'])->name('salesorder');
    Route::get('purchaseorder', [PoController::class, 'index'])->name('purchaseorder');
});
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cekUserLogin:4'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('salesorder', [SoController::class, 'index'])->name('salesorder');
});
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cekUserLogin:5'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('salesorder', [SoController::class, 'index'])->name('salesorder');
});
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cekUserLogin:6'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('salesorder', [SoController::class, 'index'])->name('salesorder');
    Route::get('purchaseorder', [PoController::class, 'index'])->name('purchaseorder');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be resolved by gates and policies. You create a user, give him roles, assign gates to the appropriate roles, give policies to individual methods. I don't quite understand why you want to rewrite some functionality that has already been implemented in the framework itself. Please have a look at the documentation. This should be the first step. There are many YouTube tutorials how to manage roles, gates and policies.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-gates-policies-guards-explained